# Visual Documentation in IDE

Tags: eclipse-plugin, coding-style, ide, documentation

I regularly get frustrated by text-overload in my IDE (Eclipse right now). I find myself separating my methods by big chunks of whitespace, and then regretting that later when I need to find something by scanning through the code.

Something I think does work well is the [GrepCode way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java) of viewing source code. Does anyone know if anything like this has been implemented in a code editor? More specifically, I want the ability to have nice, formatted and colourful documentation (preferably collapsable) to help me read my code. It could even have the ability to embed design images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Text-overload" is precisely why a plugin like [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) does exist.

> Mylyn's task-focused interface reduces information overload and makes multitasking easy.
>
> Mylyn makes tasks a first class part of the IDE, integrates rich and offline editing for ALM tools, and monitors your programming activity to create a "task context" that focuses your workspace and automatically links all relevant artifacts to the task-at-hand.
> This puts the information you need at your fingertips and improves productivity by reducing information overload, facilitating multitasking and easing the sharing of expertise.

[image: splash]

Plus you can [add to your project **WikiText**](http://tasktop.com/blog/eclipse/rich-editing-for-tasks-via-mylyn-wikitext), with Markdown support (see [WikiText FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/FAQ#WikiText), and its [User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui/help/Mylyn%20WikiText%20User%20Guide.html))

Comment: Thanks for this, but it wasn't what I was looking for. I'm aware of techniques like that but I'm looking for a within-code solution.

Comment: @alistair I understand; I don't know of a within-code solution.

Answer (score 0):

To better manage huge amounts of code, you may want to reconsider these:

- Use Eclipse Mylyn, as it will hide code that you don't work with.
- Open Windows -> Preferences, type "Folding" in the preferences dialog
  and check, which editors should provide more folding by default to
  hide non relevant things from you.
- Have a look at the Java browsing
  perspective of Eclipse. It stems from the old Smalltalk code browsing
  user interfaces and is meant to more easily manage (but not edit)
  Java code.
- If you are working much visually with your code (and remember its layout instead of the structure), you may find the [Crazy Outline view](https://github.com/jeeeyul/pde-tools#crazy-outline) very helpful. It provides an airplane layout view of your text.

If the more important aspect of your question is how to more easily see the documentation you wrote for your code, check this:

- Make sure that the JavaDoc view and the Declaraction view are opened and visible all the time to show Javadoc and declaration of whatever your cursor points at. Make sure you actually provide JavaDoc comments, to begin with.
- The Eclipse Code Recommenders project has [advanced documentation views](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/documentation/usr.html#d0e351), which basically show the results of data mining of common Eclipse code. You can get a company internal (commercial) version of that tool, so it would recommend code completion, as other code in your projects was written.